# How to preserve user input from a dropdown menu using Python

Tags: python, html

I am learning to write a web application using Python 
I am presenting the user with a simple form asking for a color (in a dropdown menu) and a number (as a text input field). 
If the number is invalid, I'd like the user to see the form again, so that she can edit the number, but I'd like the selected color stay selected.

This is the form code:

```
<form method="post">
Choose a color and a number between 1 and 100.
<br>
<label>Color
<select name="color">
<option>red</option>
<option>blue</option>
<option>green</option>
<option>yellow</option>
</select>
</label>
<label>Number<input name="number" value="%(number)s"></label>
<div>%(error)s</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Using string substitution I've managed to show the number entered by the user, but the `color` field is (of course) always reset to red. Is there a smart way to preserve the data chosen by the user in the dropdown? 
I'm thinking of the `selected` HTML keyword but how to put it into the right option?

Comment: Are you using a framework? Templating language (e.g. Jinja2)?

Comment: I'm using webapp2 framework

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you're using string formatting with the `%`. I would recommend using something like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), but even if you don't do that, you could accomplish what you want via something like this:

```
html = '''stuff here
<label>Color
<select name="color">
%(colors)s
</select>
</label>
<label>Number<input name="number" value="%%(number)s"></label>
<div>%%(error)s</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="Submit">'''

color_template = "<option %(selected)s>%(color)s</option>"
colors = [['red', False], ['blue', False], ['green', True]]
color_html = ''
for color, selected in colors:
    color_html += color_template % {'color':color,
                                    'selected': 'selected' if selected else ''}
html = html % {'colors': color_html}
```

In Jinja you could do something like this:

```
<select name='color'>
{% for color, selected in colors %}
<option {% if selected %}selected{% endif %}>{{ color }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

And provide it similar data.